# Interest that Compounds Monthly with a Monthly Deposit?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So the principle is $5$ when opening the account

The rate is $1%$ (r=.01) 
Compounded monthly. 
The account is active for 5 years. 
A deposit of $10$ is made after each month

Since I need to find the amount after each month and add $10$, $ t = \frac{1}{12} $.

So normally, I'd use $A = 5(1 +\frac{0.01}{1})^{\frac{1}{12}} $ to find the amount after one month, add $10$ and then repeat.

I would have to repeat this until I get to 60 months to find the amount after depositing $10$ each month for 5 years.

Is there a formula I can use to avoid this amount of work? This work around is what I'm supposed to find for my class. I'd really appreciate any guidance. Thank you.

Comment: Your formula for $A$ should be $A = 5(1+\frac{0.01}{12})^{1},$ I think.

Answer (score 1):

Your growth rate is the same and your deposit amount is the same each month.

Your recurrence is of the form of 
$$a_{n}=ca_{n-1}+d$$

\begin{align}
a_{n}&=ca_{n-1}+d \\
&=c(ca_{n-2}+d)+d \\
&= c^2a_{n-2}+cd+d \\
&= c^2(ca_{n-3}+d)+cd+d \\
&=c^3a_{n-3}+c^2d+cd+d \\
&\vdots\\
&=c^na_0+(c^{n-1}+\ldots+1)d \\
&=c^na_0+d\frac{1-c^n}{1-c}
\end{align}

where in the last line I used the formula for geometric series